# get json response with php

Tags: php, json, response

Im trying to use an api I was given to create a instant quote form. The form should be getting info from a form and sent to the url and respond using JSON. I've personally have only ever use JSON once but not in this way so I really don't know what Im doing right or wrong. Any help is musch appreciated.

this is my form_post.php

```
<?php
$key1=$_POST['key1'];
$First_Name=$_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
$Company_Name=$_POST['Company_Name'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Phone_1=$_POST['Phone_1'];
$Phone_2=$_POST['Phone_2'];
$Phone_Fax=$_POST['Phone_Fax'];
$Address_1=$_POST['Address_1'];
$Address_2=$_POST['Address_2'];
$Address_City=$_POST['Address_City'];
$Address_State=$_POST['Address_State'];
$Address_Zipcode=$_POST['Address_Zipcode'];
$Note=$_POST['Note'];
$Carrier=$_POST['Carrier'];
$Origin_City=$_POST['Origin_City'];
$Origin_State=$_POST['Origin_State'];
$Origin_Zipcode=$_POST['Origin_Zipcode'];
$Destination_City=$_POST['Destination_City'];
$Destination_State=$_POST['Destination_State'];
$Destination_Zipcode=$_POST['Destination_Zipcode'];
$v_year=$_POST['v_year'];
$v_make=$_POST['v_make'];
$v_model=$_POST['v_model'];
$v_op=$_POST['v_op'];
$v_size=$_POST['v_size'];
$Available_Date=$_POST['Available_Date'];
$url = 'https://www.transportautoquoter.com/ws/abd/v1/createQuote/';
$data = array('quote_id' => $quote_id, 'vehicle_count' => $vehicle_count 'deposit' => $deposit 'total' => $total 'price' => $price);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($response === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
  $json_array=json_decode($response,true); 
 function display_array_recursive($json_rec){
        if($json_rec){
            foreach($json_rec as $price=> $value){
                if(is_array($value)){
                    display_array_recursive($value);
                }else{
                    echo $price.'--'.$value.'<br>';
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }
    display_array_recursive($json_array);
?>
```

this is my script on the index.php doc

```
<script>
      function submit_by{
        var First_Name=$("#First_Name").val();
        var Last_Name=$("#Last_Name").val();
        var Company_Name=$("#Company_Name").val();
        var Email=$("#Email").val();
        var Phone_1=$("#Phone_1").val();
        var Phone_2=$("#Phone_2").val();
        var Phone_Fax=$("#Phone_Fax").val();
        var Address_1=$("#Address_1").val();
        var Address_2=$("#Address_2").val();
        var Address_State=$("#Address_State").val();
        var Address_Zipcode=$("#Address_Zipcode").val();
        var Note=$("#Note").val();
        var Carrier=$("#Carrier").val();
        var Origin_City=$("#Origin_City").val();
        var Origin_State=$("#Origin_State").val();
        var Origin_Zip=$("#Origin_Zip").val();
        var Destination_City=$("#Destination_City").val();
        var Destination_Sate=$("#Destination_Sate").val();
        var Destination_Zip=$("#Destination_Zip").val();
        var v_year=$("#v_year").val();
        var v_make=$("#v_make").val();
        var v_model=$("#v_model").val();
        var v_op=$("#v_op").val();
        var v_size=$("#v_size").val();
        var Available_Date=$("#Available_Date").val(); 
        $.post("form_post.php",{"Api_key":"itmzsxrolybe","Api_pin":"2631",”Referrer_Id”:”8”,"Shipper":{"First_Name":"First_Name","Last_Name":"Last_Name","Company_Name":"Company_Name","Email":"Email","Phone_1":"Phone_1","Phone_2":"Phone_2","Phone_Mobile":"Phone_Mobile","Phone_Fax":"Phone_Fax","Address_1":"Address_1","Address_2":"Address_2","Address_City":"Address_City","Address_State":"Address_State","Address_Zipcode":"Address_Zipcode","Note":"Note"},"Transport":{"Carrier":"Carrier","Origin":{"City":"Origin_City","State":"Origin_State","Zipcode":"Origin_Zip"},"Destination":{"City":"Destination_City","State":"Destination_Sate","Zipcode":"Destination_Zip"},"Vehicles":[{"v_year":"v_year","v_make":"v_make","v_model":"v_model","veh_op":"veh_op","v_size":"v_size"}],"Available_Date":"Available_Date"}},
        function(data){
          $("#json_response").html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Im not sure why the page seems to refresh and not show response?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's JavaScript console for errors?  You should be getting an error from this `function submit_by{`.  It would also be helpful if you showed the code that attempts to call that function, as well as the related form HTML.

Comment: fancy quotes wont work, `”Referrer_Id”:”8”,` why you not serializing the form instead of grabbing a bunch of vars by id, i feel for the next guy refactoring.